# Kohana 2 Formo Warning

Tags: php, database, kohana

Using Kohana 2 version and everything is ok. But today click Koahana website and get this error:

```
An error was detected which prevented the loading of this page. If this problem persists, please contact the website administrator.
panel/modules/formo/libraries/Formo.php [103]:
Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated
```

This 103. line:

```
call_user_func('Formo_'.$name.'::load', & $this);
```

I've never changed any file, directory vs. Why get this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The & in call_user_func says to pass the variable by reference, however doing this when calling the function (ie. call-time pass by reference) was deprecated in php 5.3.

Dropping the ampersand should sort the issue, however it would be possible to make it pass by ref in the call_user_func declaration.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php for more info.